# Shift Middle Point of Number Range

Tags: c#, math

I have a function that Normalizes any number range to a new range.

Such as
`[123,456]` to `[0,10]`
or
`[-50,50]` to `[-1,1]`

I need help shifting the middle point of the new range.

I'm using this for a GUI Slider that has a range of `[-100,100]` but controls a value of `[-2,2]`.
The GUI Slider default is `0` but the value default is `1` (none).
My program is a GUI for a CLI and I'm not able to change that program's value default to `0`.

[image: slider]

```
Slider
-100 --------------||-------------- 100
                    0
Value
-2 |  |  | -1 |  |  0|  |  | 1  |  |  2

Shifted Value
-2 |  | -1 |  | 0 | 1|  |  |  |  |  | 2
```

---

### Normalize

https://dotnetfiddle.net/42jHvM

```
// Normalize Function
public static double Normalize(double val, double valmin, double valmax, double min, double max, double midpoint) 
{
    return (((val - valmin) / (valmax - valmin)) * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

---

```
double output = Normalize(  0, // slider input
                         -100, // input min
                          100, // input max
                           -2, // normalize min
                            2, // normalize max
                            1  // middle point
                         );
```

---

### Shift Middle Point

In my example I use `[-100,100]` converted to `[-2,2]`.

The middle point of the `input` `[-100,100]` is `0`.
But I need the `output` `[-2,2]` to have a middle point of `1` instead of `0`.

So it will be skewed, slower towards `-2`, faster towards `2`.

**Example** I made in photoshop to visualize the middle point shift using a gradient.

[image: shift]

**Easing**

I tried using an [Ease Out Tween](http://www.gizma.com/easing/) to shift the middle point, but I don't know what values to use.
The example output needs to be `Min: -2`, `Mid: 1`, `Max: 2`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/nfNlBC

It uses:

```
//t: current time
//b: start value
//c: change in value
//d: duration
```

---

**After the middle point has been shifted:**

Input of `-100` should output `-2`.
Input of `-50` should output `-0.50`?
Input of `0` should output `1`.
Input of `50` should output `1.75`?
Input of `100` should output `2`.

**Before**

```
-100 | -50 | -25  |  0  |  25 |  50 | 100

 -2  | -1  | -0.5 |  0  | 0.5 |  1  |  2
```

**After** `approximated`

```
-100 | -50  | -25  |  0  |  25  |  50  | 100

 -2  |-0.50 | 0.25 |  1  | 1.25 | 1.75 |  2
```

---

### Question

How can I modify the Normalize function, or run it's output through a new Shift/Easing function to set the new middle point of the range and readjust the numbers?

Comment: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/10/find-a-polynomial-least-squares-fit-for-a-set-of-points-in-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why do you need such a mapping but the way to do it is:

```
public static double Normalize( double val, double valmin, double valmax, double min, double max, double midpoint )
{
  double mid = ( valmin + valmax ) / 2.0;
  if ( val < mid )
  {
    return ( val - valmin ) / ( mid - valmin ) * ( midpoint - min ) + min;
  }
  else
  {
    return ( val - mid ) / ( valmax - mid ) * ( max - midpoint ) + midpoint;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's giving the right output, I will test on the GUI sliders. I need it because my sliders are `-100` to `100` but the value defaults here are not all `0`, some are `1`. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq

Comment: It's working well, I was able to set certain defaults to 1 instead of 0 and they seem to scale correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways this can be done, but if linear interpolation is sufficient, then you can just use some simple stretching and compression of the input parameter with a piecewise function.

```
public static double Interpolate(double val, double valmin, double valmax, double min, double max)
{
    return (max - min) * (val - 0.5 * (valmax + valmin)) / (valmax - valmin) + 0.5 * (max + min);
}

public static double Normalize(double val, double valmin, double valmax, double min, double max, double midpoint)
{
    double m = Interpolate(midpoint, valmin, valmax, min, max);
    if (val < m) {
        return Interpolate(val, valmin, m, min, midpoint);
    } else if (val > m) {
        return Interpolate(val, m, valmax, midpoint, max);
    } else {
        return m;
    }
}
```

You should be able to replace `Interpolate` with something fancier, like one of the easing forms you linked, with the following mappings from your parameter names to theirs:

```
t = val - 0.5 * (valmax + valmin)
b = 0.5 * (max + min)
c = max - min
d = valmax - valmin
```